# Keeping values in a form even after returning from various pages

Tags: php, forms, session, stack-overflow

How does stackoverflow keep the values in their forms?

e.g. when you start filling the form for a question and you go to the main page or other pages and then going back to the question page, all values are saved.

Do they save in session? If so is it actually a good way of saving values?

Comment: This belongs to meta.SE I think.

Comment: Not really, he was asking for how to code a something similar to SE's. More of asking the *type* of technology used. @CommuSoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different methods of storing values in that manner where they can be retrieved at many times. Most of them differ on which case you are using them. Let me list a few of my favorites:

1. **Could be cookies, as cookies can be implemented in both JS and practically any server-side language. It only lasts for how long the cookie is designated to expire, or if the browser's cookies are reset.**
2. **Could be sessions, they're like server-side cookies. They last for only one session with the server. They are always transmitted via the server, unlike cookies, which are meant and stored for the client.**
3. **To me, I would prefer the HTML5 javascript `localstorage`, the reason for it being that it's so convenient, is treated like a
   traditional variable, and is made for this purpose. However, you can't view the content on the server-side, unlike sessions or cookies. But it doesn't seem to matter for this case, only for edge cases. No expiration date, unless if the browser's cache is reset.**

> Cookies and local storage really serve difference purposes. Cookies
>   are primarily for reading server-side, local storage can only be read
>   client-side. So the question is, in your app, who needs this data —
>   the client or the server?

Comment: Set my answer with a checkmark if it answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for a quick and great response! For my app is needed for the client as I think its a very handy trick to implement to the app.. But is it safe? Talking about HTML5 localstorage?

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, as I try to write my answers quickly while still being comprehensive. And I'm 14 years old, so I still have a lot to learn! Regarding your question, safe for whom? @StuckBetweenTrees

Comment: I will mark as soon as I will be able to do so.. Nvm the question, as I can check all the values on the server side anyway. P.s. You should not mention your age as you might make someone upset :)

Comment: Why would I made someone upset? That was not my intention. @StuckBetweenTrees

Comment: I think another option is storing it in the database. SO probably doesn't use the first two options, because the content survives a cookie reset (and the session id is stored as a cookie).